# ngRoute в Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня на сайте слева меню и в зависимости от выбранного пункта правая часть будет иметь принципиально различный вид. С Angular работаю недавно, поэтому хочу уточнить - я правильно понимаю, что ngRoute - это именно то, что нужно для решения этой задачи?

То есть, для каждого пункта меню я создаю свой partials и настраиваю $routeProvider так, чтобы при щелчке на новую ссылку открывался соответствующий partial.

И сразу еще один вопрос:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#/view1">view 1</a><a href="#/view2">view 2</a></li>
</ul>

<ng-view></ng-view>
```

Вот так оно сейчас.  Я так и не понял, как Angular понимает, в какой ng-view засунуть partials при щелчке по ссылке. И вообще, может ли быть два partials (и ng-view на одной странице) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам рекомендую использовать [ui-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), т.к. функционал в нем намного больше чем в стандартном роутере Ангуляра.  Вот [документация](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

А теперь ответы на ваши вопросы:

> я правильно понимаю, что ngRoute - это именно то, что нужно для решения этой задачи?

Да вы правы для реализации вашей задачи вам понадобится настроить ngRoute или *uiRouter*.

> Я так и не понял, как Angular понимает, в какой ng-view засунуть partials при щелчке по ссылке.

Так как у вас 1 `<ng-view>` то при изменении url-а Ангуляр ставит все заданные partial-ы в этот же `<ng-view>`.

> И вообще, может ли быть два partials (и ng-view на одной странице) ?

1. partials - Да , с помошью [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) .
2. ng-view - Есть такое [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/8KDK6/) но я рекомендую и правилнее будет все это сделать с [ui-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).